# Seaborn clustermap doesn't show row colors

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I generated a clustermap using `seaborn.clustermap`. I wanted to show the `row_colors` option to highlight some clusters but this is the result I got:

[clustermap with missing row_colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuo4g.png)

Here you can find my code:

```
pal = sns.light_palette('red', np.unique(labels).size)
lut = dict(zip(np.unique(labels), pal))
row_colors = pd.Series(labels, name='clusters').map(lut)
sns.clustermap(my_data, method='ward', robust=True, row_colors=row_colors)
```

However if I run the example from the seaborn documentation I don't have any problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6hSd.png)

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
species = iris.pop("species")
lut = dict(zip(species.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = species.map(lut)
g = sns.clustermap(iris, row_colors=row_colors)
```

Why does the highlighting not work in my code?

Comment: The code it self works. When I try to use your code to work with the iris dataset I get a heatmap with row colours. Could you provide what is outputted by pal and lut? My only guess is that something goes wrong there. To me it seems you only have white as a row colour as there is a larger then normal space between the dendrogram and the columns of the actual heatmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you very much for you answer error. I found out the problem. I have a MultiIndex dataframe and for some reason it doesn't plot the row_color. Actually this is the only difference with the iris example code.

And I just fixed the problem doing this:

```
sns.clustermap(my_data.reset_index(drop=True), method='ward', robust=True, row_colors=row_colors)
```

and now it works:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cfrY.png)

I don't know whether this can be considered as a bug but it looks like.
Perhaps that can help to fix it.